# REACT: Location.Search Redirecting To A Wrong Page Of The App

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I am building an e-commerce react app and currently am stuck on redirecting to the home page once the user is logged in. Am using location to search the URL and split it and take the right part of it to go to the login page else if the user is logged in it should redirect to the home page.

But the problem is that even without a user logged in, the application just redirects straight to the home page. The login page is skipped and never displayed.

Below is my loginPage code.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Form, Button, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Message from "../components/Message";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";
import FormContainer from "../components/FormContainer";
import { login } from "../actions/userActions";

const LoginScreen = ({ location, history }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { loading, error, userInfo } = userLogin;

  const redirect = location.search
    ? location.search.split("=")[1]
    : "/";

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      history.push(redirect);
    }
  }, [history, userInfo, redirect]);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(login(email, password));
  };

  return (
    <FormContainer>
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      {error && <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>}
      {loading && <Loader />}
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group controlId='email'>
          <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type='email'
            placeholder='Enter email'
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId='password'>
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type='password'
            placeholder='Enter password'
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Button type='submit' variant='primary'>
          Sign In
        </Button>
      </Form>

      <Row className='py-3'>
        <Col>
          New Customer?{" "}
          <Link to={redirect ? `/register?redirect=${redirect}` : "/register"}>
            Register
          </Link>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </FormContainer>
  );
};

export default LoginScreen;
```

And Here is my App.js code.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import ProductScreen from "./screens/ProductScreen";
import CartScreen from "./screens/CartScreen";
import LoginScreen from "./screens/LoginScreen";
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <Container>
          <Route path='/login' component={LoginScreen} />
          <Route path='/product/:id' component={ProductScreen} />
          <Route path='/cart/:id?' component={CartScreen} />
          <Route path='/' component={HomeScreen} exact />
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The Login page is never displayed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally got the problem. It was in the reducer store when i was setting the user to local storage. Instead of using **null** i was instead using **[]** and react was creating its own user.

```js
const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
  : [];
```

so i just changed it to null and everything works all fine.

```js
const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
  : null;
```